# Impedir que a EditText abra teclado quando entro no layout

Tags: android

Sempre que entro em um layout que possui um `EditText`, ele abre por padrão o teclado digital para que eu escreva algo. Gostaria de impedir isto, queria que ele mostrasse o teclado apenas quando eu clicasse no `EditText`.

Comment: Já tentou colocar o foco em outra coisa? Além disso, você não quis dizer EditText quando disse TextField?

Comment: Exato, já corrigi

Comment: Como posso fazer para tirar o foco?

Comment: Me lembrei de uma opção melhor. Veja a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar à declaração da sua `Activity` no Manifest uma das seguintes opções:

Para entrar sempre com o teclado escondido

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Para deixar como está (ou seja, se o teclado já tava aberto quando chegou nela, continua aberto. Se não estava, continua fechado):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
```

Analise qual é a opção mais adequada ao seu caso e escolha.